# Ignore a word in the middle of a string, regex

Tags: regex

Let's say we have the example, "REST THE API", and we would like to capture just "REST API", how could we do that? There may also be variations such as "THE REST API" and "REST API, THE" where we would want to always exclude the word THE.

I've been able to use seperate capture groups for "REST" and "API" but I'm unable to figure out how to create just one group for "REST API"; excluding "THE".

Here's my attempt:

```
((REST\s)(?:THE)(\sAPI))
```

This returns match groups:

```
1. REST THE API
2. REST
3. API
```

Thank you for your time.

Comment: Just concatenate groups 2 and 3, isn't that what you want?

Comment: That may be the best solution. Although, if the order is different then it doesn't seem like we would get a match.

Comment: [Will this help](https://regex101.com/r/dP9uI9/1)

Comment: It's returning those match groups because you have the whole regex wrapped in a capture group. Remove that capture group and `REST` will be in group 1, `API` in group 2.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do something like this:

```
/(REST|API)/
```

And it will match both "THE" and "API" but keep in mind that it will also match the beginnings of "THESE" and "APIZZA" and order is not enforced.

https://regex101.com/r/dP9uI9/2